# convert date mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd date itself in the format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, format

I am trying not to format `ToString()`. I need the date itself in the format.i cannot do to string
scenario:

```
string str = "02/11/2006";
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
```

now **`dt`** is in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, but i need in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`
hope i add some sense..huh!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: You are confusing the DateTime Structure with its string presentation.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you mean. If you have the date in a DateTime variable it is an universal representation of the date. If you wish to convert it back to string you can use the following:

```
        string str = "02/11/2006";
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);

        var date = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the `DateTime` [Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) with its string presentation.

if you want to convert a string with a custom DateTime format you have to use `DateTime.ParseExact` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str ,"mm/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

if you want a particular string presentation of a `DaTime` you have to use a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Answer (score 2):

A DateTime has no format (it's only data). Only String representation have one. Add this to your code :

```
String newFormatedDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

**I think you just need to know about the ToString overloads:**

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15/01/2001", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

Console.WriteLine(newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```